# fatal error in OpenCart: call to undefined function error

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I do not want to be asking a question that has already been answered, however I have done a ton of research and I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to query and add database results to OpenCart's addproduct.tpl

In the **MODEL** file I have:

```
public function units() { //function that gets database info and returns it

$unit_variables = $this->db->query("SELECT unit FROM  ". DB_PREFIX ."
weight_class_description");

if (!$unit_variables) {

die(mysql_error());

}

else {

foreach ($unit_variables->rows as $temp_var) {

print_r($temp_var['unit'], true);

}   
}   
}
```

In the **CONTROLLER** file I have:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product'); //where my function is located
$this->model_catalog_product->units();
$weight_variables = units(); 

if (isset($this->request->post['weight_variables'])){

$this->data['weight_variables'] = $this->request->post['weight_variables'];

}
```

In the **VIEW** I have:

```
<?php echo $weight_variables ?>
```

I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined function units() in /path/to/controller/file on line etc.
```

Note: When I `print_r($temp_var);` instead of returning `print_R($temp_var, true)` and delete these lines of code `$weight_variables = units(); if (isset($this->request->post['weight_variables'])){ $this->data['weight_variables'] = $this->request->post['weight_variables'] }` in the controller file my model file will display the query results on the addproduct.tpl

Comment: what is your class called ?

Comment: class ModelCatalogProduct extends Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`units()` is a METHOD of your object, yet you're calling it as a standalone regular function:

```
$weight_variables = units();
                    ^^^^^^^
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
$weight_variables = $this->model_catalog_product->units();
```

instead? And note that as-written, your method doesn't actually return anything, so `$weight_variables` will simply get assigned `null`..

Comment: Your correction fixed my error `call to undefined function` error and your correct `$weight_variables` is assigned `null`. As indicated by `Notice: Undefined variable` but why is the function not returning something, shouldn't this line return my database query `print_r($temp_var['unit'], true);`?